# Referencing old (full .NET Framework) Class Library when targeting .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-rc2, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm developing a web application on .Net Core, but as .Net Core is still on development some libraries used are not built on Core yet.

I know I can target .Net 4.6 in my application to use old libraries but I'm not sure about what actually change in the use of new .Net Core functionality inside my app.

I know this way I'm loosing multi platform capabilities but I actually don't need it at the moment insead I need going on using API and MVC unified pipeline, the integrated dependency Ingnection container and other .Net Core new functionality

Will this be aniway possible by targeting old framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short and simple answer is: You can't reference .NET Framework 4.x libraries in .NET Core project for the simple reason that it's two different frameworks and many APIs that were available in .NET 4.5/4.6 are unavailable in .NET Core.

There are some exceptions though.

1. #### If your class library does target `portable-net45-win8` you can use it.

   Because this profile makes sure that the API surface matches the one .NET Core uses and is based on `System.Runtime`. In order to be able to import such packages/libraries in .NET Core application or .NET Core class library, you need to add

   ```
   "frameworks:" {
     "netcoreapp1.0": {
       "dependencies : { },
       "imports": [ "dotnet5.6", "portable-net45-win8" ] 
     }      
   }
   ```
2. #### If your class library targets `dnx5x` / `dotnet5.x`, then they can be used with the same way as the above
3. #### If you are really really sure, your class library don't use *ANY* unsupported API and ***none*** of it's dependencies use *ANY* unsupported API

   Then you could technically use the same trick, but I would advice to **NEVER** do this, as it will allow you to import any .NET 4.x library (even 2.0 ones) and you'll never know if its supported or not. **SO DON'T DO THIS *EVER***.

   Instead, convert your class library into a Portable Class library and target `netstandard1.x` (depends on the .NET Framework version used before, see this [matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library)).

   For example, if your class library was targeting .NET Framework 4.5.1 before, then convert it to `netstandard1.2`. If there are any errors about missing API, then it was using APIs not supported by .NET Core. You'll have to fix that (remove it from the `netstandard1.2` version by using `#if !NETSTANDARD1_2` precompiler directive or try a higher netstandard version. You can also target two targets in the new project.json absed Class libraries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in my specific case I need to use Openstack.Net library to connect to CloudFiles services.
If I understood correctly I just need to check wich framework version it supports, add it to the imports section and than install the nuget package and it will hopefully work, right?

Comment: @ilFusta you can create a asp.net core app targeting both .net core and full .net framework. But, in the moment you create a reference to a package that needs the full .net framework, then your app will work only on full .net framework. I guess Visual Studio throws an error asking you to remove the reference to .net core.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.
I have a project targeting NHibernate (that depends on full .NET Framework) and also some old format Class Library projects (csproj).

I use DI and MVC/API without problems.

Comment: That's **very** unlikely to work unless you abuse `import` property in project.json and if you do abuse it (use it in a wrong/unintended way) it will at best work on Windows, but fail on Linux in some cases (depends on which API is inside the library and which of these apis are actually used

Comment: @Tseng in the question he mentioned that he knows that the solution wouldn't work in other environments. I just said it is possible. It's not the best solution, but it's possible.