# Install-Package EntityFramework.Triggers not working

Tags: triggers, asp.net-core

I am working on a asp.net core project. Here I want to use a trigger. I find a solution and that is Install-Package EntityFramework.Triggers. But in my solution I unable to install Install-Package EntityFramework.Triggers. It shows error "Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ProjectName'".

Is there any easy way to apply trigger in my asp.net core project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referencing old (full .NET Framework) Class Library when targeting .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302873/referencing-old-full-net-framework-class-library-when-targeting-net-core)

Comment: There is some lacking information, like which EF you are using (EF Core or EF6) and if you target .NET Core or .NET Framework, since ASP.NET Core runs against both. But essence is: 1. You can't use EF6 based extensions with EF Core, they are incompatible - EF Core is a complete rewrite 2. you can't use .NET Framework assemblies with .NET Core (with certain exceptions for .NET Core 2.0)