# Why does a dotnet Core App with a reference to a classic .Net project works and compiles

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I was under the impression from other questions and experience that you could not reference a classic .Net project from a dotnet Core project. [Referencing old (full .NET Framework) Class Library when targeting .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302873/referencing-old-full-net-framework-class-library-when-targeting-net-core)

However I was helping someone else with their solution and I discovered it contained a reference to a classic .Net project targeting 461 and it compiles and runs without issue. I was wondering how this can be so.

- /netcore2.1

  - References: netstandard, net261 projects
- /netstandard2.0

  - References: net261 project
- /net461 (old style csproj)

The 461 project only contains custom types and nothing else.

I removed the extra reference from the netcore2.1 project since it was already nested, so I assume it has something to do with it being referenced by a netstandard project.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46394435/1139830) explains it pretty well.

Comment: @mason Thank you for your help finding that answer.